# How can I change spell check to Turkish in Pages?

Tags: pages, spellcheck

I started to use Pages. I want to change spell check language. But I don't find Turkish in the language menu (inspector of Pages). How can I add Turkish into the language menu? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, for a language not included in OS X, you can try adding a dictionary from the OpenOffice app, as explained at

http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2011/06/extra-spell-checking-dictionaries-for.html

Unfortunately, Turkish is not there.  Here is a a site with some .dic and .aff files which I have not tested myself.

http://code.google.com/p/tr-spell/downloads/list

Comment: I tried downloading the oxt file you mentioned [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4149233?start=0&tstart=0) and changing the extension to zip, but it doesn't seem to contain dic or aff files. Is there some way to install it on OS X?

Comment: @Lauri Seems not, I guess I never followed that up to see if it was the same kind of .oxt as on the OpenOffice list.